# UIButton not responsive on it whole surface (UICollectionViewCell)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview

***The problem :***

I have a UIButton inside a UICollectionViewCell that is linked to an IBAction. The button is yellow on the screenshot ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwLa.jpg)). **The problem is that the button calls the action only when we touch a specific part of itself, not the whole zone**; approximately a zone of 20px from the bottom of the button height and the full width. (I draw this zone in red [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6ect.jpg))

***Structure of my project :***

I'm using a UICollectionView to ask the user some questions, one after another. The user can respond to those questions by touching buttons, move around a map, select a date, etc... Each questions have the same layout; a title label, a button and a view that contains the tools to answer the question. That's why I chose to use a UICollection View.

For each question, I load a specific view (from a XIB file) in the UIView in the center of the cell (green on the screenshot). The *File's Owner* of each XIB File is set to be a class that is called *@IBDesignable class typeQuestionVC: UIView {...}*.

That's in this class that I load the requested XIB and I link the buttons to an action.

***The question :***

How can I make my buttons to be responsive on the whole surface ?

***What I've tried so far :***

- I've only used AutoLayout to set the position of the button. I've
  tested and the constraints are correct.
- I've tried to use "UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)" on the
  contentEdgeInsets property of the button to be sure that there is no
  Insets.
- I've tried "*theButton*.frame = *theContainerOfTheButton*.frame"

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem ! I Needed to add this to my class : typeQuestionVC

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if(!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha>0){
        for subview in self.subviews.reverse(){
            let subPoint = subview.convertPoint(point, toView: self)
            let result = subview.hitTest(subPoint, withEvent: event)
            if result != nil{
                return result
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```